# How to comment all lines contain some text in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse to cook java. Now I have a faced this problem in several times when I want to comment all the lines that contains a specific text / variable. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + forward slash(/)

Comment: Thanx for the comment Srinivas. But I am not looking for a shortcut for /* */ing multiple lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use find/replace with regular expression, just like in current picture (replacing `div`)

[image]